# Is it possible to change the color to CSS's order property?

Tags: html, css, tags

In Firefox's inspector, I see this :

```
element {

order:35;

}
```

Is it possible to set a color to that? This is to my year outlook calendar, and I have set a special day a different color. However that color will not show up when I click on the month, viewing it larger.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why should `element` match the thing when it is "larger"? What makes it larger? Why should it change the colour when you don't have any properties in the code you provided which would affect the colour (or the background colour or the border colour or any other colour).

Comment: the `order`-property is to change the placement order of an element within a `CSS-Grid` or `Flexbox` no matter of its possition within the DOM. `order` does not change the size, color or anything else. Why should it.

Comment: Ok here is the thing I'm trying to work on

https://codepen.io/cpUserpen/pen/mdOOpmv

The special days are colored, but when I click on February for example, the 14th will not stay colored. I want it to.

Comment: It is possible to select an element through its style attribute. Hence your code uses [style="order:29"] as part of the selector for 14 February. The problem with styling the clone of this element is that the clone does not have the nth-child-of-type(2) which is the only way apparently that the calendar 'remembers' that this is February. You'll therefore have to add something to the JS when you do the cloning to pick up what the nth-child position is. I think I'd use a class right from the beginning rather than this nth-child way.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use `[style="order:29"]` and so on as part of the selector, in this case to get 14 February, the information about which month it is is lost in the clone.

This is because in the main calendar the month is selected by its nth-child-of-type position in the whole group of 12 months. The clone by contrast is just one month only.

This snippet adds another class to the months so that the knowledge of which month they are is not lost.

Then the CSS has to have more added so that the clone as well as the original month sets the required color.

This will need doing for every special day's CSS. Only the 14 February has had this added in this snippet:

```js
var monthNamesRy = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var daysOfTheWeekRy = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]

var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear(); // 2016
document.querySelector("#year").innerHTML = year;
var thisMonth = d.getMonth(); // 0 - 11
var today = d.getDate(); // 1 -31
//var nthday = d.getDay();// 0 - 7
var daysOfTheMonthDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".daysOfTheMonth");


for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
  createCalendar(month);
}



function createCalendar(month) {
  var monthDiv = createMonthHeader(month);

  //ADD class which tells us which month number it is
  monthDiv.classList.add('M' + Number(month + 1));

  var firstDayOfTheMonth = getFirstDayOfTheMonth(year, month);
  var daysinmonth = daysInMonth(year, month)
  var counter = 0,
    order = 6;

  for (var i = 0; i < firstDayOfTheMonth + 7; i++) {
    order++;
    createDay(month, "&nbsp;", order, monthDiv);
  }
  for (var i = firstDayOfTheMonth; i < daysInMonth(year, month) + firstDayOfTheMonth; i++) {
    counter++;
    order++;
    createDay(month, counter, order, monthDiv);
  }

  for (var i = firstDayOfTheMonth + daysinmonth; i < 6 * 7; i++) {
    order++;
    createDay(month, "&nbsp;", order, monthDiv);
  }


}

function createDay(month, counter, order, monthDiv) {

  //if(order == 8){order = -1}
  var day = document.createElement("div");
  if (month == thisMonth && counter == today) {
    day.setAttribute("class", "to day");
  } else {
    day.setAttribute("class", "day");
  }
  day.setAttribute("style", "order:" + order);
  day.innerHTML = counter;
  monthDiv.appendChild(day);

}


function createMonthHeader(month) {
  var calendar = document.querySelector(".calendar");



  var monthDiv = document.createElement("div");
  monthDiv.setAttribute("class", "month");
  calendar.appendChild(monthDiv);

  var h4 = document.createElement("h4");
  h4.innerHTML = monthNamesRy[month];
  monthDiv.appendChild(h4);

  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    //var order = (i == 0) ? order = 7 : order = i;
    var hday = document.createElement("div");
    hday.setAttribute("class", "day OfWeek");
    hday.setAttribute("style", "order:" + i);
    hday.innerHTML = daysOfTheWeekRy[i].toUpperCase();
    monthDiv.appendChild(hday);
  }


  return monthDiv;

  /*
  <div class="month">
    
  <div class="monthHeader">
  <div class="day OfWeek">Sun</div>
  <div class="day OfWeek">Mon</div>
  <div class="day OfWeek">Tue</div>
  <div class="day OfWeek">Wed</div>
  <div class="day OfWeek">Thu</div>
  <div class="day OfWeek">Fri</div>
  <div class="day OfWeek">Sat</div>
  </div>
        
  <div class="daysOfTheMonth">
  */
}


function daysInMonth(year, month) {
  return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate(); //29/03/2016 (month + 1)
}

/*function leapYear(year){
  return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}

function getNextMonth(month){
 if (month == 11) {
    var nextMonth = 0;
} else {
    var nextMonth = month+1;
}
return nextMonth;
}
*/
function getMonthName(month) {
  return monthNamesRy[month];
}

function getDayName(day) {
  return daysOfTheWeekRy[day];
}

function getFirstDayOfTheMonth(y, m) {
  var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
  return firstDay.getDay();
}

function getLastDayOfTheMonth(y, m) {
  var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
  return lastDay.getDay();
}


// the popp up

var calendar = document.querySelector(".calendar");
var cloneCont = document.querySelector(".cloneCont");
var requestId = false;
calendar.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (this.querySelector(".cloneCont")) {
    this.removeChild(this.querySelector(".cloneCont"));
  } else if (e.target.parentNode.className.includes('month M')) {

    var monthClone = e.target.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    monthClone.className += " cloneMonth";
    var cloneCont = document.createElement("div");
    cloneCont.className += " cloneCont";
    cloneCont.appendChild(monthClone);
    this.appendChild(cloneCont);

  }
}, false);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 80%;
  background: black;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Times, serif;
}

.calendar,
section {
  max-width: 50rem;
}

.day {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}

.day:nth-of-type(7n+1) {
  color: #f09;
}

.to.day {
  color: #07a;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}

.month {
  width: calc(2em * 7);
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: darkgoldenrod;
}

h1#year {
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 29px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Fertigo Pro, Open Sans;
  padding: 1em 1em .5em 1em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  border-bottom: 5px double #492191;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px black, 0px 2px 1px black, 0px 2px 1px black, 4px 2px 1px orange;
  color: white;
}

.no-flexbox .day {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.no-flexbox h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.no-flexbox h1 {
  width: 4em;
}


/* FLEXBOX styles*/

body,
body * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h4 {
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

h1 {
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.calendar,
.month {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 2.5em;
}

section {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
}

.month {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.day {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*for a Spanish like calendar  
  .month .day:nth-of-type(1){order:7!important;}
  .month .day:nth-of-type(8){order:-1!important;}
   
*/

script {
  display: none;
}

.cloneCont {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5em;
  margin-top: -10.89em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #ccc;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  animation: redimensionar .5s cubic-bezier(.86, 0, .07, 1);
}

.month.cloneMonth {
  display: flex
}

.month.cloneMonth:after {
  content: "\02718";
  color: #f09;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}

.cloneCont.trans> {
  transform: translateY(1000px);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: trasladar .5s cubic-bezier(.86, 0, .07, 1);
}


/*********************SPECIAL DAYS*********************/


/*   July 4th         */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(7)>div[style="order:22"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00f;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   September 5th         */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(9)>div[style="order:22"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #65557d;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   October 31st     */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(10)>div[style="order:50"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffa500;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   November 25th   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(11)>div[style="order:40"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a61;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   December 24th   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(12)>div[style="order:41"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0a0;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   December 25th   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(12)>div[style="order:42"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0a0;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   December 31st   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(12)>div[style="order:47"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: tan;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   January 1st   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(1)>div[style="order:20"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #80794f;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   February 14th   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(2)>div[style="order:29"],

/* ADDED */

.cloneCont>div.M2>div[style="order:29"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6710c9;
  text-align: center;
}


/*  March 17th   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(3)>div[style="order:32"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0a0;
  text-align: center;
}


/*  April 4th  */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(4)>div[style="order:21"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   May 30th   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(5)>div[style="order:43"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #5d839c;
  text-align: center;
}


/*   June 19th   */

.calendar>div:nth-of-type(6)>div[style="order:35"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f2c035;
  text-align: center;
}


/*********************SPECIAL DAYS*********************/

@keyframes redimensionar {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes trasladar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 id="year"></h1>
  <div class="calendar"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I now understand how it works. So this will nee doing for every special day's CSS. Nothing needs to be done in the JavaScript?

Comment: Tried it on my blog, but didn't work. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors (or CSS warnings) in your browser's devtolos inspect facility console? And is the M2 class being set correctly in that element?

Comment: I've just noticed that your first comment asked 'nothing needs to be done in the Javascript'. I don't understand that comment as in the answer I have explained that another class is being added to the months (to remember which month it is). Have a look at the JS in the answer - have you copied that to your system?

Comment: Yes, I added it. It made my page go blank. What do you mean by set correctly? I will check Firefox inspector for errors and warnings.

Comment: Ok I see it's working now. Maybe it needed a refresh.